# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Error: Function st_geomfromkml(unknown) doesn't exist

Tags: java, postgresql, postgis

I am working with a Partner on a project for university and my goal is to upload geometrycal data to our PostgreSQL database. The reason why I ask is, that the code is executable on her computer while on mine there appears the in the title mentioned error message (the code crashes later on on her computer as well but that is because of something that is not of interest for me now).

```
try (PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO "+scheme+".\"s0559289_GO\" (name, geom)\n"
        + "VALUES ('" + "test1" + "'," + " ST_GeomFromKML('<LineString>\n" +
        "<coordinates>-23.02,32.43\n" +
        "-71.16,42.23</coordinates>\n" +
        "</LineString>'));", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);) {

    int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdate();
```

As I already mentioned that the code is working for her. This is why I thought that maybe using another IDE is the reason, I even downloaded IntelliJ Ultimate, because I get it for free as a student but it didn't help.

edit:
the rest of the error message looks like this:

```
Hinweis: Keine Funktion stimmt mit dem angegebenen Namen und den Argumenttypen überein. Sie müssen möglicherweise ausdrückliche Typumwandlungen hinzufügen.
Position: 64
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2477)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2190)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:169)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:136)
    at KMLController.addKMLGeoObject(KMLController.java:26)
    at GisConn.main(GisConn.java:31)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

2nd edit:
I use:Windows 10
Partner uses: Ubuntu (sadly I don't know which version and cant look it up at the moment)

Comment: Is the PostGIS extension installed on that database?

Comment: It seems you're missing the postgis extension

Comment: at least in my db I get a proper geometry with `SELECT ST_GeomFromKML('<LineString><coordinates>-23.02,32.43 -71.16,42.23</coordinates></LineString>')`

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure but the PostGIS extension hast to be installed on the Database and not on my computer, right? Then shouldn't my partner be able to use the same code succesfully?

Comment: @Daligro yes, the extension should be installed in the database via `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` : check -> https://postgis.net/install/

Comment: @JimJones then I'm sure this extension is already  installed, do you have another idea? Or would there be an explanation for why my partner doesnt require the database to have this extension installed while i do?

Comment: @Daligro keep in mind that the extension can be installed in a different database of your server. For instance, installing it at the maintenance db `postgres` does not mean it will be available in the database `mydb`. It might be also possible that it is installed but in another `schema`, which would mean that you have to explicitly tell where the functions are `myschema.ST_...`.

Comment: @JimJones That makes absolutely sense to me, but sadly its all hardcoded at the moment, which means that even though we access the same database, scheme, table with the same network but get different results. I really appreciate your help and i am totally clueless but at the moment I don't understand how this could be the problem, because of the fact we do the same but get different results. btw. I use Windows and she uses ubuntu

Comment: If PostGIS is installed in a schema different than `public`, it has to be in your search path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407622/postgis-not-available-for-all-postgres-users/48422325#48422325