# How to fix 'SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR' on postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I hava a function trigger that feed a column with a geometry converted from another column with json. It was working without problems until recently, when i started getting this error: ' SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR ...  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.'

This is the script for my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_formulario_ep()
RETURNS trigger AS $teste_trigger$
BEGIN
UPDATE formulario.formulario_ep
SET geom = (SELECT ST_GeomFromText( ST_AsText( CAST(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geom_js) AS TEXT) ), 4326 ));
RETURN NEW;
END;
$teste_trigger$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And this is the script for the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_allrows_trigger_ep
AFTER INSERT ON formulario.formulario_ep
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_formulario_ep();
```

Comment: where is `geom_js` coming from? it could be simplified by having a BEFORE trigger and writing `NEW.geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(NEW.geom_js),4326);` instead of the entire update statement

Comment: Otherwise, if the input `geom_js` is fine, it means that the schema where PostGIS is installed (IF it is installed...) is not in the search path of the user running the function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407622/postgis-not-available-for-all-postgres-users/48422325#48422325

Comment: geom_js comes together with the other fields from a web form.

Comment: I would replace `SET geom =...` for this `BEFORE trigger and writing NEW.geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(NEW.geom_js),4326); `?

Comment: Well, I tell you what. You got me to the right place with your question, I had similar error, and it turned out to be a trigger and I didn't even know we had triggers in our DB! So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the schema where PostGIS is installed is available in the search_path of the user that do the insert, as detailed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407622/postgis-not-available-for-all-postgres-users/48422325#48422325).

Also your trigger could be greatly simplified by making it a `BEFORE` trigger, allowing to simply set the `NEW.geom` value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_formulario_ep()
RETURNS trigger AS $teste_trigger$
 BEGIN
   NEW.geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(NEW.geom_js),4326);
   RETURN NEW;
  END;
$teste_trigger$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER update_allrows_trigger_ep
BEFORE INSERT ON formulario.formulario_ep
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_formulario_ep();
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem was with the user i was using to insert on the db.