# PostGIS is installed in Cloud SQL but cannot find PostGIS_full_version()

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, postgis, google-cloud-sql

I created postgis extension using `CREATE EXTENSION postgis WITH SCHEMA database`.

Extension is present in list of extensions (`SELECT * FROM pg_extension`)

postgis version 2.5.1.

But Select PostGis version (`SELECT PostGIS_full_version();`) is not working.

```
ERROR:  function postgis_full_version() does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
```

I am using google cloud.

What is wrong? How should I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [postgis not available for all postgres users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407622/postgis-not-available-for-all-postgres-users)

Comment: @JGH, nope... .

Comment: Do you mean that you installled Postgis extension on Google Cloud PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2):

> `CREATE EXTENSION postgis WITH SCHEMA database`

If you want to use a non-default schema, say `foo`, then you'll need to call `select foo.postgis_full_version()`

**But you probably don't want to specify a schema at all**. In PostgreSQL, all function calls default to the `public` schema unless you specify otherwise. So `select postgis_full_version()` is the same as saying `select public.postgis_full_version()`.

Try running:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Comment: having the schema in your search path is enough

Comment: Right, by default only `public` is in the search path.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be with a PostGIS version 2.5. According to official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions#postgis) PostGIS 2.3 extension family is supported for Google Cloud SQL. The installation instructions you can find [here](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/postgis_installation.html).