# Postgres/PostGIS st_distance_sphere function with EntityManager.createQuery incomprehensible error

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, postgis

I try to calculate the distance between two points using PostGIS. I figured out that postGIS has `st_distance_sphere function` for this, and tried the code below:

```
private fun getDeliveryDistance(areaCentroid: Point, buyerLocation: Point): Double {
    val query = em.createQuery(
        "select st_distance_sphere(st_makepoint(${areaCentroid.x}, ${areaCentroid.y}), st_makepoint(${buyerLocation.x}, ${buyerLocation.y}))",
        Double::class.java
    )
    val result = query.singleResult
    return result
}
```

but instead of correct result i got the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'st_distance_sphere' {originalText=st_distance_sphere}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       +-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
       |  +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'st_makepoint' {originalText=st_makepoint}
       |  \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       |     +-[NUM_DOUBLE] LiteralNode: '38.970335125923135'
       |     \-[NUM_DOUBLE] LiteralNode: '45.0543938370861'
       \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
          +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'st_makepoint' {originalText=st_makepoint}
          \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
             +-[NUM_DOUBLE] LiteralNode: '38.97033512592316'
             \-[NUM_DOUBLE] LiteralNode: '45.05439383708615'
 [select st_distance_sphere(st_makepoint(38.970335125923135, 45.0543938370861), st_makepoint(38.97033512592316, 45.05439383708615))]]
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea about this error. But when I copy the query in debug mode or from last line of stack trace before calling `getSingleResult()` and then execute it in pgAdmin console, I get the correct result. Does somebody know how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Query(
    """select topology.st_distance(topology.st_makepoint(:restaurantLat, :restaurantLong), topology.st_makepoint(:buyerLat, :buyerLong))""",
    nativeQuery = true
)
fun calculateDistance(
    @Param("restaurantLat") restaurantLat: Double,
    @Param("restaurantLong") restaurantLong: Double,
    @Param("buyerLat") buyerLat: Double,
    @Param("buyerLong") buyerLong: Double
): Double
```

I just specified postgres schema explicitly and it solved my problem

Comment: 2 things: Coordinates must be expressed as longitude first, then latitude. If you have to specify the schema for PostGIS functions, it will fail sooner than letter. You must set PostGIS schema in the user `path`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48422325/7635569

Comment: ST_Distance with long-lats will return a distance in degrees (which is meaningless), not in meters, unless you cast the geometries to geographies